# Magento 2 - I'm upgrading magento 2.1 to 2.3.5 but compile command returning error

Tags: magento2.3, php-7, magento-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade magento 2 version to the latest version by following commands

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Above commands executed successfully. When run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` getting below error in command line -

```
An exception was raised while creating "Application"; no instance returned#0 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'application', 'Application')
#1 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('application', 'Application')
#2 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Application', 'application')
#3 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#4 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(261): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Application')
#5 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(57): Zend\Mvc\Application::init(Array)
#6 /public_html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#7 {main}

An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned#0 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'request', 'Request')
#1 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('request', 'Request')
#2 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Request', 'request')
#3 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#4 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(113): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Request')
#5 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ApplicationFactory.php(29): Zend\Mvc\Application->__construct(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager))
#6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\ApplicationFactory->createService(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'application', 'Application')
#7 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'application', 'Application')
#8 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'application', 'Application')
#9 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('application', 'Application')
#10 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Application', 'application')
#11 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#12 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(261): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Application')
#13 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(57): Zend\Mvc\Application::init(Array)
#14 /public_html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#15 {main}

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php on line 426#0 /public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, '"continue" targ...', '/home/rewardpor...', 426, Array)
#1 /public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#2 /public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/rewardpor...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Zend\\Stdlib\\Arr...')
#4 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/Parameters.php(29): spl_autoload_call('Zend\\Stdlib\\Arr...')
#5 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-console/src/Request.php(96): Zend\Stdlib\Parameters->__construct()
#6 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-console/src/Request.php(122): Zend\Console\Request->getParams()
#7 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-console/src/Request.php(66): Zend\Console\Request->params()
#8 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/RequestFactory.php(29): Zend\Console\Request->__construct()
#9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\RequestFactory->createService(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'request', 'Request')
#10 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'request', 'Request')
#11 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'request', 'Request')
#12 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('request', 'Request')
#13 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Request', 'request')
#14 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#15 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(113): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Request')
#16 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ApplicationFactory.php(29): Zend\Mvc\Application->__construct(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager))
#17 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\ApplicationFactory->createService(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'application', 'Application')
#18 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'application', 'Application')
#19 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'application', 'Application')
#20 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('application', 'Application')
#21 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Application', 'application')
#22 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#23 /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(261): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Application')
#24 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(57): Zend\Mvc\Application::init(Array)
#25 /public_html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#26 {main}
```

I have PHP 7.1 version.

Am I missing any other command to run before compile?

Or what should I do to compile successfully?

Answer (score 0):

MAgento 2.3. works on  [php 7.2 or Higher](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

please Update You PHP version and Also

Use

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Instead Of

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I tried with 7.2 and with 7.3 but then `php bin/magento cache:clean` command also throwing same error. Even `cache:clean` command working with php 7.1. And still other commands throwing same error with 7.2 and 7.3

Comment: do you have installed are the required PHP Modules in  7.2?

Comment: No, which modules? Can you please list here?

Comment: See Here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html

Comment: See Verify installed extensions Section

Comment: I Checked, and all are enabled in phpinfo().

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the PHP version

Answer (score 0):

Hi  this is definitely a PHP version error. I had Magento 2.1.2 and the Godaddy hosting server was running PHP 7.3. After downgrading PHP to version 5.6, problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should also upgrade the PHP version, because you are also upgrading the Magento